# Google Place Details - opening_hours doesn't include diverging opening hours

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

While the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details) doesn't literally say so I would expect the opening hours from the Google Places API to adapt to diverging opening hours from the Google My Business page.

I implemented this API to show the opening hours of my parents business on the website in the hopes that my parents could easily change these, and add diverging hours and days. Now it seems like these aren't included, and the opening hours will just stay the same, no matter if the current day is a one time closing day for example.

Am I using the wrong API for this, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is not implemented in Places API yet.

There is a feature request in the public issue tracker to add special hours. Please have a look at [issue 10145](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=10145).

Google has accepted this feature request, however there is no ETA exposed.

I can suggest staring the issue to add your vote and receive further updates from Google.

Comment: Thanks, at least they're working on it then. It'll be a lot more work if I have to implement using the My Business API, which apparently does have the special hours field.

Comment: Hi could you please look into this issue. https://stackoverflow.com/q/68394011/8894627