# Get a day from opening_hours google autocomplete API

Tags: swift, autocomplete, google-places-api

I need to get a day from restaurant opening hours(Autocomplete) api. I can get opening and closing hours and could not get the day. This is my code.

```
     if place.openingHours?.periods != nil{
        let period = place.openingHours?.periods as! NSArray
        print(period)
        for i in 0..<period.count{
            let day = (period[i] as AnyObject).openEvent?.day
            print(day)
            let Open = "\((period[i] as AnyObject).openEvent.time)"
            print(Open)
            let Close = "\(String(describing: (period[i] as AnyObject).closeEvent!.time))"
            print(Close)
        }
    }
```

Response for Periods:

Business Status: Operational
(
"Open: Day 3, Time (09:00); Close: Day 3, Time (17:00)",
"Open: Day 4, Time (09:00); Close: Day 4, Time (17:00)",
"Open: Day 5, Time (09:00); Close: Day 5, Time (17:00)",
"Open: Day 6, Time (09:00); Close: Day 6, Time (17:00)",
"Open: Day 7, Time (10:00); Close: Day 7, Time (17:00)"
)

When i print the day it returns
Optional(__C.GMSDayOfWeek). Please help me.
Thanks in advance

Comment: share the response of `period`.

Comment: I have shared. Business status is the response. Please check below the code

Comment: but there i can't find day key.

Comment: yes it is not like normal dictionary. That is the problem.

Comment: so now you want to show week days from open and close

Comment: yes. here Day 3 is actually tuesday. but i cannot get that day. it returns only "__C.GMSDayOfWeek"

Comment: check here : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/ios-sdk/reference/interface_g_m_s_opening_hours

Comment: I have already gothrough all the documents. Cant find the solution.

Comment: can you find weekdatText in that?

Comment: No i cannot find